# Moss 2007 - Intermittent password prompt Issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am working in Moss 2007 and users gets password prompt intermittently even though they enter correct user name and password .  There is no time frame when they get this issue . We are using NTLM authentication.  When we checks ULS logs we fount out below errors.

We don't have custom code in the application.We are also in contact with the Microsoft to address this issue. Please let me know if anyone needs any more details to suggest your thoughts.

We got confirmation from respective teams that there are no issues neither from DB side nor network side. There is no patches are applying during this time and no Anti Virus has been applying during this time.

I appreciate quick response.

Moss version: 12.0.0.6421 (SP2)
Windows - Windows server 2008 R2 (SP1)
IIS : 6.0

12/08/2014 19:53:11.06  w3wp.exe (0x0CBC)       0x0958  Windows SharePoint Services    General                8kh7                High       Unable to connect to database.  Check database connection information and make sure the database server is running.

12/08/2014 19:53:11.06  w3wp.exe (0x0CBC)       0x0958  Windows SharePoint Services    General                8m90                Medium               3785 heaps created, above warning threshold of 32. Check for excessive SPWeb or SPSite usage.     ​

- 12/08/2014 19:53:11.06  w3wp.exe (0x0CBC)       0x0958  Windows SharePoint Services    General                0                Monitorable       Potentially excessive number of SPRequest objects (3772) currently unreleased on thread 12.  Ensure that this object or its parent (such as an SPWeb or SPSite) is being properly disposed. This object is holding on to a separate native heap.